# Firebase Realtime Database not updating data using React and useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I have a React component that serves as a form to input and update data related to cash transactions in Firebase Realtime Database. The component uses the useState and useEffect hooks to manage form state and populate the form with existing data for editing.

The problem is that the data is not being updated in Firebase when I submit the form. Data insertion for new entries also seems to be failing. I've double-checked my Firebase configuration and database rules, and they appear to be correct.

Here's a summary of the relevant code:

```
// ...

const CashInputForm = ({ editItem, onSubmit }) => {
  const initialState = {
    name: '',
    type: 'Cash',
    chequeNo: '',
    shop: '',
    selectedDate: new Date(),
    cash: '',
    chequeAmount: '',
    expenses: '',
    account: '',
  };

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState(initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Effect to populate form data when in edit mode
    // ...
  }, [editItem]);

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Submit form data to Firebase Realtime Database
    // ...
  };

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    // Function to update form data on input change
    // ...
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      {/* Form inputs */}
      {/* ... */}
    </form>
  );
};
```

export default CashInputForm;
I suspect the issue might be related to the way I'm handling the form data or the Firebase API calls inside the handleSubmit function. I'm looking for assistance in identifying the problem and ensuring that both data insertion and updates work as expected in Firebase Realtime Database.

Any insights, suggestions, or code improvements are highly appreciated! Thank you.

this is the full code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { ref, push, set } from 'firebase/database';
import { format } from 'date-fns';
import { database } from '../firebase';
const shops = [
  'Buddima Samudra',
  'Togs',
  'Dress Point',
  'Buddima Super VT',
  'Buddima Super NK',
  'Filling Station',
];

const CashInputForm = ({ editItem, onSubmit }) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [type, setType] = useState('Cash');
  const [chequeNo, setChequeNo] = useState('');
  const [shop, setShop] = useState('');
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [cash, setCash] = useState('');
  const [chequeAmount, setChequeAmount] = useState('');
  const [expenses, setExpenses] = useState('');
  const [account, setAccount] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (editItem) {
      setName(editItem.name);
      setType(editItem.type);
      setChequeNo(editItem.chequeNo.toString());
      setShop(editItem.shop);
      setSelectedDate(new Date(editItem.date));
      setCash(editItem.cash.toString());
      setChequeAmount(editItem.chequeAmount.toString());
      setExpenses(editItem.expenses.toString());
      setAccount(editItem.account.toString());
    }
  }, [editItem]);

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Convert chequeNo to a number or set it to 0 if empty
    const chequeNoValue = chequeNo === '' ? 0 : parseInt(chequeNo, 10);

    // Create a reference to the 'cashbook' table in Firebase
    const cashbookRef = ref(database, 'cashbook');

    // Set the default value of paidcheque to 0
    const paidchequeValue = 0;

    if (editItem) {
      // If editItem exists, update the data in Firebase
      const dataToEditRef = ref(cashbookRef, editItem.key);
      set(dataToEditRef, {
        name,
        type,
        chequeNo: chequeNoValue,
        shop,
        date: format(selectedDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
        cash: parseFloat(cash) || 0,
        chequeAmount: parseFloat(chequeAmount) || 0,
        expenses: parseFloat(expenses) || 0,
        account: parseFloat(account) || 0,
        paidcheque: paidchequeValue,
      })
        .then(() => {
          console.log('Data successfully updated in Firebase!');
          // Clear input fields after successful submission
          setName('');
          setType('Cash');
          setChequeNo('');
          setShop('');
          setSelectedDate(new Date());
          setCash('');
          setChequeAmount('');
          setExpenses('');
          setAccount('');
          onSubmit({
            // Pass the edited data back to the parent component
            name,
            type,
            chequeNo: chequeNoValue,
            shop,
            date: format(selectedDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
            cash: parseFloat(cash) || 0,
            chequeAmount: parseFloat(chequeAmount) || 0,
            expenses: parseFloat(expenses) || 0,
            account: parseFloat(account) || 0,
            paidcheque: paidchequeValue,
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error('Error updating data in Firebase:', error);
        });
    } else {
      // If editItem doesn't exist, add new data to Firebase
      push(cashbookRef, {
        name: name || '',
        type,
        chequeNo: chequeNoValue,
        shop: shop || '',
        date: format(selectedDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
        cash: parseFloat(cash) || 0,
        chequeAmount: parseFloat(chequeAmount) || 0,
        expenses: parseFloat(expenses) || 0,
        account: parseFloat(account) || 0,
        paidcheque: paidchequeValue,
      })
        .then(() => {
          console.log('Data successfully saved to Firebase!');
          // Clear input fields after successful submission
          setName('');
          setType('Cash');
          setChequeNo('');
          setShop('');
          setSelectedDate(new Date());
          setCash('');
          setChequeAmount('');
          setExpenses('');
          setAccount('');
          onSubmit({
            // Pass the new data back to the parent component
            name,
            type,
            chequeNo: chequeNoValue,
            shop,
            date: format(selectedDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
            cash: parseFloat(cash) || 0,
            chequeAmount: parseFloat(chequeAmount) || 0,
            expenses: parseFloat(expenses) || 0,
            account: parseFloat(account) || 0,
            paidcheque: paidchequeValue,
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error('Error saving data to Firebase:', error);
        });
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="name"
          className="block w-full p-2 border rounded-lg"
          value={name}
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
          required
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="type">Type:</label>
        <select
          id="type"
          className="block w-full p-2 border rounded-lg"
          value={type}
          onChange={(e) => setType(e.target.value)}
          required
        >
          <option value="">Select a type</option>
          <option value="Cash">Cash</option>
          <option value="Cheque">Cheque</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      {type === 'Cheque' && (
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="chequeNo">Cheque No:</label>
          <input
            type="number"
            id="chequeNo"
            className="block w-full p-2 border rounded-lg"
            value={chequeNo}
            onChange={(e) => setChequeNo(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
      )}
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="shop">Shop:</label>
        <select
          id="shop"
          className="block w-full p-2 border rounded-lg"
          value={shop}
          onChange={(e) => setShop(e.target.value)}
          required
        >
          <option value="">Select a shop</option>
          {shops.map((shop) => (
            <option key={shop} value={shop}>
              {shop}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="selectedDate">Date:</label>
        <input
          type="date"
          id="selectedDate"
          className="block w-full p-2 border rounded-lg"
          value={format(selectedDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd')}
          onChange={(e) => setSelectedDate(new Date(e.target.value))}
          required
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="cash">Cash:</label>
        <input
          type="number"
          id="cash"
          className="block w-full p-2 border rounded-lg"
          value={cash}
          onChange={(e) => setCash(e.target.value)}
          required
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="chequeAmount">Cheque Amount:</label>
        <input
          type="number"
          id="chequeAmount"
          className="block w-full p-2 border rounded-lg"
          value={chequeAmount}
          onChange={(e) => setChequeAmount(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="expenses">Expenses:</label>
        <input
          type="number"
          id="expenses"
          className="block w-full p-2 border rounded-lg"
          value={expenses}
          onChange={(e) => setExpenses(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="account">Account:</label>
        <input
          type="number"
          id="account"
          className="block w-full p-2 border rounded-lg"
          value={account}
          onChange={(e) => setAccount(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <button
        type="submit"
        className="bg-gradient-to-r from-blue-500 to-green-500 hover:bg-gradient-to-r hover:from-blue-400 hover:to-green-400 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
      >
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default CashInputForm;
```

gives me this error

```
ERROR
db._checkNotDeleted is not a function. (In 'db._checkNotDeleted('ref')', 'db._checkNotDeleted' is undefined)
ref@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:14934:22
handleSubmit@http://localhost:3000/main.b3e2e7191f845113559c.hot-update.js:71:83
callCallback@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:47078:23
dispatchEvent@[native code]
invokeGuardedCallbackDev@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:47122:33
invokeGuardedCallback@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:47179:40
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:47193:34
executeDispatch@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:51337:46
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:51363:26
processDispatchQueue@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:51374:41
dispatchEventsForPlugins@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:51383:27
batchedUpdates$1@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:65935:18
batchedUpdates@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:46926:34
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:51542:21
dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49048:42
dispatchEvent@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49042:88
dispatchDiscreteEvent@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49019:22
dispatchDiscreteEvent@[native code]
```